# Android AutoCompleteTextView setText filter is always true

Tags: android, kotlin, drop-down-menu, android-spinner, autocompletetextview

I am using `AutoCompleteTextView` as a Spinner as implemented in [material design, as Exposed Dropdown Menus](https://material.io/develop/android/components/menu). I am trying to set a default value but it's not working.

[image: k]]

I have an array of values which has to be set in that `AutoCompleteTextView`.

```
val TYPE_OF_LANGUAGES = arrayOf("C", "C++", "Java", "Python", "Pearl", "Kotlin")

// Set the Language adapter
val adapter: ArrayAdapter<String?> = ArrayAdapter<String?>(
     context,
     R.layout.spinner,
     TYPE_OF_LANGUAGES
)
binding.spinner.apply {
        this.setText(adapter.getItem(0).toString(), false)
        this.setAdapter(adapter)
}
```

This line of code

```
 this.setText(adapter.getItem(2).toString(), false)
```

sets the 3rd item "Java", but on clicking the `AutoCompleteTextView` I am able to see only "Java" in the dropdown menu, even filter is set to `false`.

Comment: Try setting adapter first and only after set text to text view.

Comment: I tried that too... It's the same... @JeneaVranceanu

Answer (score 2):

Add simple **TouchListener** for *AutoCompleteTextView* .
Below code works fine to me. Try this

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
            override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                spinner.showDropDown()
                return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
            }
        })
```

Comment: Is 'spinner' a layout? use this in adapter 
          " android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line insted" of "R.layout.spinner" see this image - https://ibb.co/dmMQyjz

Comment: Yesh spinner is a layout I created, which has just a ```TextView```.

Comment: use  "R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item" and give "AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView" id to spinner and apply above method. Does above image match your expectation?

Comment: use  "R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item" and give "AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView" id to spinner and apply above method. Does above image match your expectation?